# Convert mediumDate() to other format (with Locale) on Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, converters, jodatime

I've a problem to convert a date in other format in java (I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)). In fact, I've a formatted local date as is:

```
24/giu/14 (Italian format date...but other local formats are possible)
```

I would like to see this in output (using Locale format date):

```
24/06/2014
```

I tried to build a sample code, but doesn't works...what am I doing wrong?

```
public String DateConvertFromMediumFormatToSlash (String date)
    {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate().withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        LocalDate dt = dtf.parseLocalDate(date);

        return dt.toString(); // output: 2014-06-24
    }
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Exactly what is your input? Exactly what do you want as your output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is confusing with regards to what you have as input and what you want as output.

## Italy Uses Hyphens, Not Slashes

But one problem seems to be the slashes. Joda-Time expects hyphens not slashes. Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3 showing you what a LocalDate looks like as a String using the medium format for Locale of Italy.

```
LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate( 2014, 6, 24 );
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate().withLocale( Locale.ITALY );
System.out.println( "output: " + formatter.print( localDate ) );
```

When run…

```
localDate: 2014-06-24
output: 24-giu-2014
```

## Define A Formatter For Slashes

So if you want to parse/generate a string with slashes instead of the hyphens expected for Locale of Italy, you must explicitly define such a formatter.

```
String input = "24/giu/14";
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MMM/yy").withLocale( Locale.ITALY );
LocalDate localDate = formatterInput.parseLocalDate( input );
System.out.println( "localDate: " + localDate );

DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yy").withLocale( Locale.ITALY ); // Locale not needed here, but it's a good habit to specify.
String output = formatterOutput.print( localDate );
System.out.println( "Output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
localDate: 2014-06-24
Output: 24/06/14
```

---

By the way, using two digits for the year is asking for trouble IMHO.

Comment: Ok! Thanks man! :) you're right! But, I don't understand a thing: how can I set the output pattern based on Locale? In example, italian date is dd/MM/yy...but, for example, the english pattern is not the same...how can I manage this, in according to your solution? Thanks!! :)

Comment: @user3449772 You seem to have ignored my entire answer. The Italian date is *not* `dd/MM/yy`. My third line of code shows exactly how to get a format for a particular locale.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I lost a piece because of  I reading from my smartphone at the moment! I think that is the best solution for me! Thanks man! Sorry for misunderstanding... :)